# Svelte: Selection not updating [CSS ISSUE]

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a Svelte Selection that fetches data and displays it in a dropdown. Users can select various properties, and this functionality works well. However, now I want to preselect certain options; despite trying various approaches, I have been unable to make it work for some reason.

```html
{#if properties.length > 0 && selectedProperties.length > 0}
<div class="pb-16">
    <label for="propertyDropdown">Select Company Properties:</label>
    <select id="propertyDropdown" bind:value={selectedProperties} on:change={handlePropertySelection}
            class="styled-dropdown"
            multiple>
        {#each properties as {name, label}}
        <option title={name} value={name}>{label}</option>
        {/each}
    </select>
</div>
{/if}
```

I call this method `onMount` to prefill the selection by setting `selectedProperties`:

```js
let selectedProperties: string[];
...
const handleCodeReceived = async function (code: string) {
    try {
        accessToken = await handleAuthentication(code) ?? "";
        if (accessToken) {
            properties = await fetchCompanyProperties(accessToken);

            const selectedOptions = Array.from(properties.filter((property) => !property.hidden).map((option) => option.name));
            selectedProperties = selectedOptions;
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        errorMessage = error.message;
    }
};
```

Note that the manual selection works just fine and the moment I manually want to select one element the preselected elements are suddenly now also selected. This also proves that the `selectedProperties` array is getting filled with the right data, there just seems to be some sort of problem with the Svelte UI State. Help is greatly appreciated.

```js
const handlePropertySelection = (event: Event) => {
    const selectElement = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    const selectedOptions = Array.from(selectElement.selectedOptions).map((option) => option.value);
    selectedProperties = selectedOptions;
};
```

I

Comment: A [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/84382a694b3d41c4be9dea513eadb95e?version=4.2.12) with a stripped-down version of your code and a time-out loop to simulate fetching data seems to work just fine even with preset options. Could it be that you interfere with the `selectedProperties` variable somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas Hennes REPL I found out that the actual issue was unrelated to the initial code and is somewhat moronic.

Turns out the selection logic works just fine. The CSS just made it look like it is not selected:

```css
.styled-dropdown option {
    /*This line messed with it: 
    background-color: #fff;*/
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am leaving this answer just in case someone stumbles upon the problem as me.